# How can I commit with cloned submodule in my repo?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-commit, git-add

I have created a repo for my `.vim` directory so that I won't need to donfigure that every time I change a machine I am working on.

So I have something like that now:

```
user@.vim$ tree -L 3 -a
.
|-- autoload
|   `-- pathogen.vim
|-- bundle
|   |-- jedi-vim
|   |   |-- after
|   |   |-- AUTHORS.txt
|   |   |-- autoload
|   |   |-- build
|   |   |-- CONTRIBUTING.md
|   |   |-- ftplugin
|   |   |-- .git
|   |   |-- .gitignore
|   |   |-- .gitmodules
|   |   |-- jedi
|   |   |-- LICENSE.txt
|   |   |-- plugin
|   |   `-- README.rst
|   |-- vim-colors-solarized
|   |   |-- autoload
|   |   |-- bitmaps
|   |   |-- colors
|   |   |-- doc
|   |   |-- .git
|   |   `-- README.mkd
|   |-- vim-surround
|   |   |-- doc
|   |   |-- .git
|   |   |-- .gitignore
|   |   |-- plugin
|   |   `-- README.markdown
|   `-- xmledit
|       |-- build.vim
|       |-- doc
|       |-- ftplugin
|       |-- Makefile
|       `-- README.mkd
`-- .git
    |-- //*** MY GIT REPO
```

And when I do `git add .` or any other `add` I cannot add `jedi` directory to my local repo.

This is the only `.gitmodules` file I have there:

```
$ cat ./bundle/jedi-vim/.gitmodules
[submodule "jedi"]
        path = jedi
        url = git://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git
```

This is what I get on `git status`

```
#       modified:   bundle/jedi-vim (untracked content)
```

What should I do to get this done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-add the submodule. There is something inconsistent.

remove the `.gitmodules`, do a `git rm --cached path/to/submodule` and remove any entries for it in your `.git/config`.

now add it again with

```
git submodule add url path
```